Viewport (3d-view) problems in macOS 18.1?
Has anyone else experienced problems in the Blender viewport after upgrading to macos 18.1?
I have been working for several weeks on a sailing ship model without incident. However, when I opened up the model after upgrading to macos 18.1, I immediately started seeing objects appear and disappear in the viewport upon slight rotations of the viewing angle or sideways motions.
I took some screen captures to illustrate what I mean. In the first, the mainsail is visible. In the second, as a result of only slightly rotating the view, the mainsail vanishes. In the third, another slight rotation makes the mainsail "battens" also disappear.
Is this something that can be corrected in Blender? Or is this a bug that should be reported to Apple? Does anyone know?
Or am I the only person who has experienced this? I don't THINK there's a problem with my file, since I never saw this until I upgraded my os, but I suppose I could be wrong.




I'm not a Mac user so I'm not sure how it all works, but that looks like a GPU driver issue to me. Most times (on Windows) when I experience weird viewport bugs like this, updating the GPU driver fixes it for me. But yeah, idk; if you just updated OS then the drivers should be up to date as well. Maybe see if you can force it to update to the latest version or maybe manually downgrade to the last driver version if you are up to date and see if that fixes it. Then you can at least know where the issue lies.
